# NsNumberFormatter not giving correct result

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am facing an issue but couldn't seem to find a solution.I have a textfield where user is entering numbers.The issue is that when the user enters last digit as zero after decimal place,it is not taking.e.g. - 42.70 is printed as 42.7.Find the code below

```
  NSNumberFormatter *_numberFormatter =[NSNumberFormatter new];
     _numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits=2;
    _numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits=1;
    _numberFormatter.roundingMode=kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling;
    _numberFormatter.allowsFloats=YES;
    _numberFormatter.groupingSeparator=@",";
    _numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator=YES;
    _numberFormatter.groupingSize=3;
   _numberFormatter.minimum=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    [_numberFormatter setLenient:YES];
    [_numberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:NO];
```

and

```
NSNumber *number = [nf numberFromString:combinedString];
    NSString *formattedString = [nf stringFromNumber:number];
```

formatted string is printing the value entered sans 0 if entered in last place but it prints the correct number if any other digit is there like 42.78 is printed as it is but 43.70 is printed as 43.7.

Am i missing setting some parameters.Any help is needed

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both

```
_numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
_numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
```

if you always want to print two digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: I tried doing that but then even if user types 4 in the text box,it would return as 4.00 and he won't be able to type further.So can't do that.

Comment: @dead_soldier, try to use two formatters, one for input, one for output

Comment: @dead_soldier: Do you replace the text in the textfield while the user is typing?

Comment: @MartinR I am doing the formatting in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method.So user is seeing what he is typing.

Comment: @dead_soldier: So what do you want exactly? When the user types "4.2", do you want to replace it by "4.20" or should it stay like it is?

Comment: @MartinR yes,if a user types 4.2 then it should become 4.20 but not the other way around.It is working fine with all the digits like 4.78 or 3.05 but not working for the above mentioned case.

Comment: @dead_soldier: I am sorry, I still don't understand (it may be my fault). What do you mean by "not the other way around"? - Does  vikingosegundo's remark help (using two formatters)? - Perhaps you can  show the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method.

Comment: @MartinR:Sorry for unclear explanation.User is seeing what he is typing when he types any digits like 44.56 or 55.06 or 78.92 i.e non zero last digit at 2nd place after decimal.But when the user types 43.80 he does not sees 43.80 but 43.8 .In shouldChangeCharactersInRange method I am allocating numberformatter as shown above.Now it is ok if user types 43.8 and he is shown 43.80 but not the case when he types 43.80 and is shown 43.8   I know from processing view,43.80 is same as 43.8 but doesn't give good user experience.So wanted to show it as said above.Hope now it helps

Comment: @dead_soldier: Please show your shouldChangeCharactersInRange code, that makes it easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25667/discussion-between-dead-soldier-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:47.78];
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:n]);
```

it will print 47.78

Comment: It is printing the digits after decimal correctly even now,but the issue is with when user types 0 at the end like 12.50.It is not returning 12.50 but 12.5 .I know it is same but it is needed to shown to the user as 12.50

Answer (score 0):

Found out that we have to do manipulations to add a zero from our side.iOS works in a weird way and doesn't allow it.So below is my code.Hope it is helpful for others also.

```
NSArray *formatArr = [combinedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *str = [formatArr lastObject];
    NSString *code;
    if ([str length] >0) {
        code = [[formatArr lastObject] substringFromIndex: [str length] - 1];
        if ([str isEqualToString:@"00"])
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if ([combinedString hasSuffix:@".0"])
            {
                formattedString=[formattedString stringByAppendingString:@".0"];
            }
            else if ([code isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                formattedString = [formattedString stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([combinedString hasSuffix:@".0"])
        {
            formattedString=[formattedString stringByAppendingString:@".0"];
        }
    }
```

Combinedstring is the input user is entering.I am checking for the '.' place and checking if the last digit is zero.If it is,then adding a zero from my own.Now user is able to see 43.50 when he types it instead of 43.5